# Error with using google maps api v2 in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I create an app view maps using google maps api v2. This is my code:

My Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
```

My main_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Android manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB96b4lWziSteDtMTqrDDurcTvOIwzKCRE" />
```

And when I running, this is logcat:

```
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demogooglemap/com.example.demogooglemap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    07-21 17:53:33.734: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
```

Plz help!

Answer (score 3):

Your min sdk is 8

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Below api level 11 you need to use `SupportMapFragment` and extend `FragmentActivity`.

Change this

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Change this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Missing few permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Follow

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on to what @Raghunandan has said, you also need to make sure the device knows what version of google play services you are using. implement this into your manafest too (inside application).

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"  />
```

Also make sure you have imported google-play-services_lib into your workspace and declared that your project is using the services (in the android properties of said project).